# WPF Display image which was created in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, image

In my WPF application I have a list of images (Tiles = child of image), but I have no idea how to display them in runtime. My code don't display them.

Here is the code:

```
private List<Tile> tiles;
    private static Random rng = new Random();

    public Window_game()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tiles = new List<Tile>();
        tiles = getTiles();
        shuffle(tiles);
        display(tiles);


    }

    private void display(List<Tile> list)
    {
        foreach(Tile tile in list)
        {
            tile.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
            gridActualTile.Children.Add(tile);

        }
    }

    private void shuffle(List<Tile> list)
    {
        int n = list.Count;
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
            Tile value = list[k];
            list[k] = list[n];
            list[n] = value;
        }
    }

    private List<Tile> getTiles()
    {
        List<Tile> list = new List<Tile>();

        // c - castle
        // r - road
        // f - field
        // e - erb

        // once occurs in a game
        list.Add( new Tile(getSource("Images/city4.png")));
        list.Add(new Tile(getSource("Images/road4.png")));
        list.Add(new Tile(getSource("Images/city3s.png")));
        list.Add(new Tile(getSource("Images/city3r.png")));
        list.Add(new Tile(getSource("Images/city2we.png")));

        return list;
    }

    private ImageSource getSource(string str)
    {
        Uri imageUri = new Uri(str, UriKind.Relative);
        BitmapImage imageBitmap = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window_game"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window_game" Height="700" Width="700"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    WindowStyle="None"
    >
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\grass.png" TileMode="Tile" Stretch="Uniform" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,700,700"/>
</Window.Background>
<Grid x:Name="Grid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="108"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="249*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="34*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="gridActualTile" Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="156*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="36*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="155*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    </Grid>
    <Image x:Name="BackButton" Source="Images\back_icon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" Margin="12,0,0,11.6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="55" Opacity="0.9" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Background="#9999" >
        <Label x:Name="label_player1" Content="Player one" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="5" FontSize="20" FontFamily="ConcursoItalian BTN Wide" Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Image x:Name="redMeeple1" Source="Images\redMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Left="14" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="redMeeple2" Source="Images\redMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Left="44" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="redMeeple3" Source="Images\redMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Left="74" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="redMeeple4" Source="Images\redMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Left="104" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="redMeeple5" Source="Images\redMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="redMeeple6" Source="Images\redMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Left="164" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="redMeeple7" Source="Images\redMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Left="194" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="frame1" Height="100" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="210" Source="Images\frame.png">
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.45" ScaleY="1.05"/>
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
        </Image>

    </Canvas>

    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="100" Margin="0,0,-0.4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Background="#9999" >
        <Label x:Name="label_player2" Content="Player two" Canvas.Right="10" Canvas.Top="5" FontSize="20" FontFamily="ConcursoItalian BTN Wide" Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Image x:Name="blueMeeple1" Source="Images\blueMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Right="14" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="blueMeeple2" Source="Images\blueMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Right="44" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="blueMeeple3" Source="Images\blueMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Right="74" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="blueMeeple4" Source="Images\blueMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Right="104" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="blueMeeple5" Source="Images\blueMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Right="134" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="blueMeeple6" Source="Images\blueMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Right="164" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="blueMeeple7" Source="Images\blueMeeple.png"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Canvas.Right="194" Canvas.Top="35"/>
        <Image x:Name="frame2" Height="100" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="210" Source="Images\frame.png">
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.45" ScaleY="1.05"/>
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
        </Image>
    </Canvas>

    <Button x:Name="Button_fakeBack" Opacity="0" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="55" Margin="12,0,0,11.6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="55" Click="Button_fakeBack_Click" MouseEnter="Button_fakeBack_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Button_fakeBack_MouseLeave" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <Image x:Name="actualTile" Source="Images\Tiles\city1rwe.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="70" Margin="312,0,311.6,19.6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="70" DragEnter="actualTile_DragEnter" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>






</Grid>
```

Does anyone know, where's the problem?

Comment: please, show your xaml